# where can i to download the "mod_wsgi.so" 

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

i want to deploy my django site to apache , but i cant find a website to download "mod_wsgi.so" file ,

i download modwsgi in http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/ , but i cant find "mod_wsgi.so" too,

this is the file :

[image]

so what can i do ,

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a precompiled Windows version you could take a look at [at the download page of the site you posted](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DownloadTheSoftware?tm=2#Windows_Binary_Downloads)

Comment: Correct, Windows binary .so files are available from the mod_wsgi site, although those are only 32 bit and not 64 bit. Thus, must use a 32 bit Apache and 32 bit Python installation.

Comment: Should also point out that the download page at 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DownloadTheSoftware' also references binaries being available for ActiveState Python. In that case they provide both 32 bit and 64 bit binaries.